# Blocked suspended to Ready suspended

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

Let's say a process is waiting for I/O in the Blocked/suspend state and then the event occurs. Why that process goes to Ready/suspend state and not directly to Ready state?
It could go directly to Ready state and save some effort of the mid-term scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Ready/suspend generally mean that the process is in some sort of secondary or temporary memory, and can't be "ready" until it is brought back into main memory.